# Provide onclick dynamically and avoid duplicate event calling

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-nestable

I try to add an item, just like this sample: https://codepen.io/Gobi_Ilai/pen/LLQdqJ

```
var addToMenu = function () {
  var newName = $("#addInputName").val();
  var newSlug = $("#addInputSlug").val();
  var newId = 'new-' + newIdCount;

  nestableList.append(
    '<li class="dd-item" ' +
    'data-id="' + newId + '" ' +
    'data-name="' + newName + '" ' +
    'data-slug="' + newSlug + '" ' +
    'data-new="1" ' +
    'data-deleted="0">' +
    '<div class="dd-handle">' + newName + '</div> ' +
    '<span class="button-delete btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right" ' +
    'data-owner-id="' + newId + '"> ' +
    '<i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' +
    '</span>' +
    '<span class="button-edit btn btn-success btn-xs pull-right" ' +
    'data-owner-id="' + newId + '">' +
    '<i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>' +
    '</span>' +
    '</li>'
  );

  newIdCount++;

  // update JSON
  updateOutput($('#nestable').data('output', $('#json-output')));

  // set events
  $("#nestable .button-delete").on("click", deleteFromMenu);
  $("#nestable .button-edit").on("click", prepareEdit);
};


 var deleteFromMenu = function () {
            var targetId = $(this).data('owner-id');
            var target = $('[data-id="' + targetId + '"]');
            var textConfirm = "Are you sure to delete" + target.data('name') + " ?";

                var result = confirm(textConfirm);
                if (!result) {
                    return;
                }

            // Remove children (if any)
            target.find("li").each(function () {
                deleteFromMenuHelper($(this));
            });

            // Remove parent
            deleteFromMenuHelper(target);

            // update JSON
            updateOutput($('#nestable').data('output', $('#json-output')));

        };
```

And after that try to delete one of the records. The page asked to confirm the question (1+added record) times.
For example, if try to add 2 records, and try to delete one item(not last added item), 3 confirm message appears.

How could I manage `$("#nestable .button-delete").on("click", deleteFromMenu);` to see only one confirm question.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.off()`. The `.off()` method removes event handlers that were attached with `.on()`.

So in your case:

```
 $("#nestable .button-delete").off().on("click", deleteFromMenu);
```

Comment: I afraid the solution leading to just the last button affected. How about the second solution to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60387074/9071943) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `removeEventListener` or [`off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove an event listener before.

```
$("#nestable .button-delete").off().on("click", deleteFromMenu);
$("#nestable .button-edit").off().on("click", deleteFromMenu);
```

**Updated (Give the better solution)**

If `#nestable` is static, you should move the listener event outside the `addToMenu` method.

> Format: `$(staticAncestors).on(eventName, dynamicChild, function() {});`

**So in your case**

```
// set events
  $("#nestable").on("click", '.button-delete', deleteFromMenu);
  $("#nestable").on("click", '.button-edit', prepareEdit);

var addToMenu = function () {
  ....
  // update JSON
  updateOutput($('#nestable').data('output', $('#json-output')));
};
```

Read the following post to have a better understanding.

[Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: @مهدی نبوی  I've just given another solution, please take a look at

Comment: Dear @Phong , Shree provide answer sooner, will change accepted answer on case your answer get's more vote, anyway thank you so much.